# Problem with an NSString and UITableViewCell

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios4

I have a big UITableViewCell which has a text from an NSString from internet. Then that string is shown ok on an NSLog, but when shown on the cell shows strange characters at the start of the text, like this:
[image]

And it randomizes the characters every launch. I'm not formatting the string in any way, so I can't understand why it shows fine on NSLog but on on the celL. Thanks in advance!

This is the code I use to get the NSString:

```
for(NSDictionary *d in userInfo) {

        description = [d objectForKey:@"description"];
    }
```

And I load it on the cell using this:

```
cell.textLabel.text = description;
```

Comment: How are you sending this to NSLog? And does `userInfo` a collection of multiple dictionaries?

Comment: just after ending the NSDictionary `for`

Comment: Can you put the code in? It looks like you are enumerating `userInfo` and setting description to a value which then gets overwritten in the next enumeration.

Comment: What code? Now the random chars is solved but the first six or seven chars are deleted of it

Comment: Try putting the NSLog call inside the for loop. See what that gets you.

Comment: Aren't you overwriting the `description` variable for every item in the `userInfo` collection?

Comment: nope because description is only one NSString

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that I was adding random garbage, because that text was used before now on a simple UITextView. Recoding the wayt it gets the description worked, thanks all who helped!

Answer (score 0):

Well I am not quite sure what you are trying to log but it kinda seems like Twitter with MGTwitterEngine

either way you would want to run somthing like this!

```
NSLog(@"Request Suceeded: %@", connectionIdentifier);
```

Then this

```
NSLog(@"See dictionary: %@", d);
```

and your text

```
cell.textLabel.text = description;
```

should look more like

```
[cell.detailTextLabel setText:[(yourClass*)[desc objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]   
 description]];
```

and one more thing if you are trying to collect from twitter "user" is a dictionary and description is a NSSTRing in it so that would look more like

```
-(NSString*)user {

return [[contents objectForKey:@"user"] objectForKey:@"description"]  ; 



  }
```

Hope this helps !